# Determine if the number of open brackets "(" equal the close brackets ")"

Tags: algorithm, string

Given a string in the following format:

```
"(1 AND (2 OR 3) AND 4)"
```

What is the fastest way to determine if the number of "open" brackets **"("** equal the "close" brackets **")"**.

**NOTE:** The string could be several hundred characters longs.

Comment: in general, a few hundreds, is "small" by today's standard. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a simple counter that starts with 0.

When you encounter "(", increase it by one. When you encounter ")", decrease by one.

If the counter isn't 0 at the end, you've got a mismatch.

Also, as others have mentioned, if the counter ever becomes negative, this means a situation such as `)(` has occured. Signal an error and stop further parsing.

Comment: Yes, although if the OP is then going to go on to parse those logical expressions this will probably be a step that's gained for free by the parser.

Comment: Also if you ever get a `counter < 0` you know they're unbalanced.

Answer (score 5):

1. Initialise counter to zero.
2. Iterate through the characters of the string.

   a. On an opening parenthesis, increase the counter.

   b. On a closing parenthesis, decrease the counter.

   c. Error out if the counter is negative.
3. Error out if the counter is not equal to zero after the loop.

This also catches cases like `)(`, which do have a matching number of opening and closing parens, but should probably be considered erroneous anyway.

Comment: That "catch" isn't really special because, in the above algorithm, the '(' is never even seen because an error is detected on the unbalanced ")" prefix.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to count that the number of `(` match the number of `)`, just run through the string once maintaining a counters, incrementing if you see a `(` and decrementing if you see a `)`. This is `O(n)` and you can't do better; you have to inspect every character.

However, I suspect you meant to ask a different question. Namely, how do you tell if the `(` balance with the `)`. In this case, you maintain a stack and you push whenever you see a `(` and you pop when you see a `)`. If ever you try to pop when the stack is empty, the parentheses are not balanced. If the stack is not empty when you reach the end of the input string, the parentheses are not balanced.

Of course, you can just mimic this with a counter, but it's more natural to think about from the perspective of a stack.

Comment: A stack is not needed. As other answers have indicated, a negative count indicates a ')' not matched by a previous '('.

Comment: "Of course, you can just mimic this with a counter, but it's more natural to think about from the perspective of a stack."

The O(1) space counter is just as "natural" as the O(m) space stack -- the counter simply tracks the stack depth.

Comment: @Jim Balter: I think the stack is more natural because if you want to deal with multiple types of brackets (e.g., `(`, `{`, `[`), it's cleaner to use a stack than to have multiple counters.

Answer (score 0):

It's O(n).  There is no way around it.  Here is a rough idea.

```
For i=0 to string.length
   if string[i] == ')'
        add to rightBracketCount
   else if string[i] == '('
        add to leftBracketCount
end for
```

compare rightBracketCount to leftBracketCount

Answer (score 0):

:)
You can

```
int left = "your string".split("(").length()
int right = "your string".split(")").length()
boolean ok = (left == right)
```

Of course this is stupid, but it is just another way